# AJAX call not returning -- success function not being executed in Django

Tags: django, jquery

I am doing AJAX calls using jQuery in Django. Everything seems to be working fine except that the ajax call is not being returned as a result the success function is not being executed. This is my jquery file

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/contact_us/",
          data: {
            'name': name_val,
            'email': email_val,
            'message': message_val,
            'subject': subject_val,
            'cc': cc_val,
          },
          success: function() 
          {

            // display success message and reset values in the form fields
            $("#reply-message").html('Your message has been sent!').fadeOut(3000, function() {});
            // clear the fields
            $("#contact-name").val("");
            $("#contact-email").val("");
            $("#contact-message").val("");
            $("#contact-subject").val("");


          }

        });
```

I do not know what to return in the view for an AJAX call so right now I am just returning a dummy message, but it is not working. Here is the views.py

```
def contact_us(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.POST.get('name', False)
            email = request.POST.get('email', False)
            message = request.POST.get('message', False)
            subject = request.POST.get('subject', False)
            cc = request.POST.get('cc', False)

            recipients = ['abc@gmail.com']
            if cc:
                recipients.append(email)

            from django.core.mail import send_mail
            send_mail(subject, message, email, recipients)
            return_message = "Sent mail"
            return Httpresponse(return_message)
```

The return_message is dummy, I don't even want to process it in my response. But why is the ajax call not returning,  rest everything is working fine and I am also receiving the mail.

I just realsed that I had made a very stupid mistake I have written Httpresponse whereas it has to be HttpResponse. Now it is working absolutely fine

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any immediate problems with your code. If you have Firebug, open up the 'Net' tab and you should be able to see the response code received and inspect the response. You should be getting a '200 OK'.

Another debugging option - try putting in the following:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/contact_us/",
          data: {
            'name': name_val,
            'email': email_val,
            'message': message_val,
            'subject': subject_val,
            'cc': cc_val,
          },
          success: function() 
          {
            // display success message and reset values in the form fields
            $("#reply-message").html('Your message has been sent!').fadeOut(3000, function() {});
            // clear the fields
            $("#contact-name").val("");
            $("#contact-email").val("");
            $("#contact-message").val("");
            $("#contact-subject").val("");
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
          {
              alert(errorThrown);
           }

        });
```

That should tell you what the problem is if the Ajax call fails.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your success function isn't being executed is probably because you aren't returning valid xml. jquery checks the data coming in to see if its the right format, aka xml because you are using the ajax call.

Reformat your data, or switch to a different jquery call.

from the jquery website on the ajax call.

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array A function to be
>   called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will
>   be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

Edit: Additional info from the jquery site, check your MIME type for the return:

> Note: We must ensure that the MIME type reported by the web server
>   matches our choice of dataType. In particular, XML must be declared by
>   the server as text/xml or application/xml for consistent results.

Comment: I am not returning any Data in the success call, its like when the function falls off the end then I want to do the success task

Comment: I am refering to your django function, the HttpResponse(return_message) is not valid xml. Therefore the jquery ajax call isn't firing off your success function because the http response type isn't set correctly. You can change the type your ajax call is expecting to text and it will then fire you success. Also hook in the error functions and see what they tell you.

Comment: As I have edited above the problem was not with the xml, the thing was I had made a typo. Anyways thanks alot for the help

Comment: Brilliant answer thanks. That was the exact reason with my request. Plus 1 it is :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, but here it is.

Are you passing a [CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) with your ajax requests?

To explicitly do this with each request, add the token to the data being sent to the server

```
$.ajax({
...
data: {
...
csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
...
},
...
});
```

If you want the token to be sent automatically with each request, then you'll have to jump through the hoops described in the link.

Either way, be sure to add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to you `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list in your `settings.py` file.